# Prove that any positive integer of the form $4n+1$ must have a prime fator of the same form.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is my work. In order to solve the exercise I supposed that all  prime factors are of the form $4k+3$ and see what will happens next. If $p_{1}, ..., p_{l}$ are the primes in the factorization of $4n+1$ we get something like $4n+1=4d+3^{l}$, that is, $4(n-d)=3^{l}-1.$ From here I conclude that $3^{l}-1$ is a multiple of $4$, but it is not true in general. Take for example $3^{3}-1=26$. But when I took $l=2$ Ive got $3^{2}-1=4.2$. So I didn't solved the exercise. Any hint?

Comment: What about $9$?

Comment: $$3\cdot7=21$$ $$(4a-1)(4b-1)=4(\cdots)+1$$

Comment: The other claim is true, by the way.  Any positive integer of the form $4k+3$ must have a prime factor of that form.  But the claim you want is false.

Comment: I think this problem is impossible because it's not true.

Comment: This is a question form Burton's book Abstract Álgebra.